# Unable to get PHP syntax right

Tags: php, syntax

I am unsure how to get the correct syntax to add in some php to this :

```
    $day = $workDays[$weekIndex][($col - 1) % 7] == TRUE ? '<SPAN class="' . $class . '"onclick="Materialize.toast(\'<?= "Hello World"\')" >' . $dkey  .'</SPAN>' : $dkey; // Defines SPAN to style related days, otherwise defaults
```

The hello world echo is the part that I cant get right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're using `'` to echo out the `<span>`, and `"` for your `onclick`. While you are correctly escaping your apostrophes, you're not escaping your quotation marks (`"`).

As such, your PHP string is evaluating as:

```
onclick="Materialize.toast(\'<?= "
```

To remedy this, also place backslashes (`\`) in front of your quotation marks. Also note that you'll need a space before the `onclick` (to separate it from the class):

```
$day = $workDays[$weekIndex][($col - 1) % 7] == TRUE ?
'<SPAN class="' . $class . '" onclick="Materialize.toast(\'<?= \"Hello World\"\')" >'
. $dkey  .'</SPAN>' : $dkey; // Defines SPAN to style related days, otherwise defaults
```

Hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 1):

If you're already processing the string with PHP, you do not need to include PHP tags to echo out `Hello World`. Instead, this value can be included inline with the other text.

```
$day = $workDays[$weekIndex][($col - 1) % 7] == TRUE 
    ? '<SPAN class="' . $class . '" onclick="Materialize.toast(\'Hello World\')">' . $dkey  .'</SPAN>' 
    : $dkey;
```